# Issue with Camera on certain devices

Tags: android, camera

i have some sort of a `LauncherApp`(start other apps easy from my app). On some devices i mentioned that the `Camera` is not in the `PackageManager`:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfo = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

This is because on this Devices the `Camera` is not an Application, but an Activity in the `Gallery`-Application!

The Problem is that my whole logic is based on `ApplicationInfos` and not `ActivityInfos`!

I managed to get the ActivityInfo of the Camera via an intent:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
camera.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ActivityInfo actInfoCamera = camera.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0);
```

now with `actInfoCamera` i can retrieve the icon of the camera and the Label. Which is all i need. But again my whole program is now based on `ApplicationInfo`. So i would need to cast or transform the `ActivityInfo` into an `ApplicationInfo`(For sorting, retrieving Icons and labels and so on).

When i try so with:

```
actInfoCamera.applicationInfo;
```

i am back at the beginning, the `ApplicationInfo` now has again the icon of the `Gallery` and the Label `Gallery`... or when i try that:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfoCamera = (ApplicationInfo) actInfoCamera;
```

it doesn't work cast from `ActivityInfo` to `ApplicationInfo` is not possible..

So i got **two questions:**

**1)** Is there a way to determine if the camera on that device is an single application or an activity within the Gallery application. Because i don't want to add two times the same camera application in my list in my app. Also please notice that it is possible that the user have some other camera apps which includes "camera" in their packagenames. I'm afraid it isn't that easy...

**2)** How do i get the `activity` of my `camera` within the `gallery` package as an `ApplicationInfo` to accomplish an easy way of implementing in my whole logic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!